# Use NVidia discrete via Nouveau on Optimus laptop

Tags: xorg

I've been reading documentation and testing things out, but I can't figure out how to have the NVidia discrete graphics always render everything onto the Intel graphics in my Optimus laptop using Nouveau (on Xorg).
1) Is this possible?
2) How is this done?
From what I've read, several docs/sites seem to imply that this is impossible on a muxless laptop.

Answer (score -1):

If your laptop has all of its display outputs connected to the Intel, and ONLY to the Intel, then yes, everything has to be passed trough the Intel card. If however some of your outputs are connected to the Nvidia card, then setting the Nvidia as your primary GPU and passing only the data for the respective displays through the Intel card would be possible. A good documentation on how to do that can be found [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PRIME#Reverse_PRIME).